# Running through command prompt( Possibly Path error?)

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, path, command-prompt

I have a problem when compiling my code from Notepad++ when i compile example( javac StudentApp.java). It does not compile but instead i get this error code - "is not recognised as an internal or external command operable program or batch file".
I use Windows 8 - well 8.1 now.
This is my path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;append
```

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You have installed Oracle JDK, haven't you?

Comment: I have but im not sure if i have installed the correct one tho which one should I have installed (Just checking)

Comment: I do not see `bin` directory of JDK in your path.

Comment: How could i modify it to put it in?

Comment: Sorry if i look really stupid here i'm just unfamiliar with knowledge of the Path file and all. And i'm really lost here and still clueless as to why its not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

First be sure you have installed JDK , but not the JRE (jre comes without the javac).

Here's how you can the **JAVA_HOME\bin** to your path (in case you have installed JDK):

```
for /f  "delims=" %j in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6" /v JavaHome') do @set jreg=%j
set jreg=%jreg:    JavaHome    REG_SZ    =%
setx PATH "%jreg%\bin";%PATH%
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone i got my solution i left out the bin directory which was " C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;" at the start of my path. Hope this helps anyone else with the same problem.